# sql server кодировка

Tags: sql-server

ms sql server studio 18, существует база данных , нужно хранить какие-то данные на турецком языке, server автоматом переводит на английские буквы, скажите пожалуйста как исправить ? Collation стоит на Cyrillic_General , Windows Code Page(1251)

Comment: поставить юникод? в кодировке 1251 есть только русский и английский

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков,для существующей таблицы как изменить кодировку не подскажете ? через свойство пытался изменить выдает ошибку

Comment: Да вроде в гугле пока не забанили, вторая ссылка по запросу "изменить кодировку таблицы mssql"
https://glax.org/kod/izmenit-kodirovku-bazy-dannykh-tablitsy-ili-otdelnogo-polya-sql/

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, этот метод не работает